# Moving Data in Processing for Twitter App?

Tags: java, api, twitter, processing

I am creating a twitter feed, which will display five tweets at a time.

The tweets update every five minutes. Once a new tweets is found, I want the tweet at the top to move off the screen, and the new tweet to go into the the last position, with every tweet moving up one position to allow this.

```
import com.francisli.processing.http.*;

HttpClient client;

HashMap Tweetzer = new HashMap();


int results_to_show = 5;
int updateTime = 10000;
int updateDiff = 0;

void setup()
{
    size(612, 612);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
}

void tweetUpdate()
{
    if(millis() > (updateTime + updateDiff))
    {
        client = new HttpClient(this, "search.twitter.com");
        client.GET("search.json?q=dublin&rpp="+results_to_show+"&result_type=recent");
        updateDiff = millis();
    }  
}



void mouseReleased()
{
    tweetUpdate();
}

void draw()
{

}

void responseReceived(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
{
    if(response.statusCode == 200)
    {
        JSONObject allresults;
        allresults = response.getContentAsJSONObject();
        //JSONObject timeline_tweets = response.getContentAsJSONObject();

        for (int i=0; i<results_to_show; i++)
        {
            text(allresults.get("results").get(i).get("text").stringValue(), 50, 10+(i*100), 400, 400);
        }

    }

    else
    {
        text("UH-OH" + response.getContentAsString(), 50, 50);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `LinkedList` in Java would be a good solution for this. `LinkedList.remove()` will git rid of the oldest item and `LinkedList.add()` will add a new one to the Queue. Check the documentation for the [Queue Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) for more information. Here is a simple example below:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

LinkedList myList;
int count = 1;

void setup() {
  myList = new LinkedList();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    myList.add(count++);
  }
  frameRate(2);
}

void draw() {
  myList.remove();
  myList.add(count++);
  println(myList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it. I understand this code inside out, but as always, I'm having a problem applying it to my code. I'd be really grateful if you could point me in the right direction